# Missing packages on raspbian

Tags: apt, packages, raspbian-buster

I'm trying to install the [libindi](https://github.com/indilib/indi/) astronomy toolset on my Raspberry PI 3 uname gives me

> Linux raspberrypi 4.19.58-v7+ #1245 SMP Fri Jul 12 17:25:51 BST 2019
>   armv7l GNU/Linux

```
cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)"
```

For libindi I need to pre-install some packages:

```
sudo apt-get install libnova-dev libcfitsio-dev libusb-1.0-0-dev zlib1g-dev libgsl-dev build-essential cmake git libjpeg-dev libcurl4-gnutls-dev libtiff-dev
```

It works when I install packages on my desktop under Ubuntu, but I have no luck so far on Raspberry:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libnova-dev
E: Unable to locate package libcfitsio-dev
E: Unable to locate package libgsl-dev
E: Unable to locate package libjpeg-dev
E: Unable to locate package libcurl4-gnutls-dev
E: Unable to locate package libtiff-dev
```

I did `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`, but it does not help. I have seen many guides where other people get this indilib successfully installed (like [here](https://hackaday.io/project/21088/instructions) or [here](https://stargazerslounge.com/topic/280387-setting-up-headless-raspberry-pi-3-for-indi-focuser/)).

How can I get those packages on my raspi without installing other OS image like ubuntu?

**UPDATE**

`sudo apt update` works without any error

```
Get:1 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster InRelease [15.0 kB]
Get:2 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian buster InRelease [25.1 kB]     
Get:3 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster/main armhf Packages [13.0 MB]
Get:4 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian buster/main armhf Packages [213 kB]
Get:5 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster/contrib armhf Packages [58.7 kB]
Get:6 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster/non-free armhf Packages [103 kB]
Get:7 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster/rpi armhf Packages [1360 B]
Fetched 13.4 MB in 19s (720 kB/s)                                              
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
```

Content of /etc/apt/sources.list

```
deb http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/ buster main contrib non-free rpi
# Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'
#deb-src http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/ buster main contrib non-free rpi
```

/etc/apt/sources.list.d/raspi.list

```
deb http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ buster main ui
# Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'
#deb-src http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ buster main ui
```

Comment: No problem here. Do you get any errors from `sudo apt update`? And what is the output of `apt policy libnova-dev`? Please update your question with this info

Comment: Ditto, they're all available.  Edit in the output from `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` and `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/raspi.list`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, after running `sudo apt update` again I was able to install all missing packages.